# Unknown Database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a very strange issue wth mySQL.

Yesterday a Db from a server was disappear.

if I log on to phpmyadmin panel i see the DB on the left side menu of phpmyadmin panel but if try to open it  (click on it) i got the error "No database slected".

If i run `show DATABASES;` i see it on the results, but i can't do any operation with that name.

I tried to run (from command line from the server)

```
mysqlcheck -u root -p -A
```

(that would check all databases), but the first message i recieve is

```
mysqlcheck: Got error: 1049: Unknown database '<db_name>' when selecting the database
```

And the procedure stop itself without continuing with other DB.

The problem is that i can't  restore or recreate it, because the name seems to be in tables schema of mysql.

Any suggestion on what's happen and how to solve it?
I simply want to clean my situation and remove the "corrupted" DB from the databases list

Comment: Check according directory in the datadir. Does it exists?

Comment: I looked for the datadir key in my.cf file to see its location, but it doesn't exist. So I guess I need to find it in /var/lib/mysql. In /var/lib/mysql I will see ibdata1 and the all databases folder.
I see that the DB folder name probably has the hexadecimal value, in fact I see "nameofDB@0022H" instead of "nameofDB-H" (as i see on phpMyAdmin panel)
Maybe the problem is that in the DB name there is the special character "-" (minus).

Comment: *I looked for the datadir key in my.cf file* ?? As I understand the server starts, and it is accessible. Simply look at `SELECT @@datadir;`. *in fact I see "nameofDB@0022H" instead of "nameofDB-H"* You may try to stop MySQL, rename folder then start MySQL and check for DB accessibility.

Comment: SELECT @@dirdata; returns '/var/lib/mysql/'.
I tried the shutdown/rename operation. Now the folder has the correct name, but from phpMyAdmin the name I see in the DB trees is #mysql50#dbname-H and it is still inaccessible.

Comment: *SELECT @@dirdata; returns '/var/lib/mysql/'.* ?? MySQL does not know about `dirdata` option variable.

Comment: what do you mean. The dir data is  '/var/lib/mysql/'. what's wrong with that?

Comment: There exists `datadir` option in MySQL, `dirdata` not exists.